# Build dynamic relationship in ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have access to API endpoints to only get, cannot suggest or apply any modifications.

This a sample schema of each api:

```
var person = DS.Model.extend {
    firstName: DS.attr(),
    lastName: DS.attr()
}

var credit = DS.Model.extend {
    name: DS.attr(),
    personId: : DS.belongsTo('person')
}

var debit = DS.Model.extend {
    name: DS.attr(),
    personId: : DS.belongsTo('person')
}
```

I can get api/person, api/credit, api/debit individually. After fetching the data. I want to map relationship between person and credit/debit similar to this...

```
var person = DS.Model.extend {
    firstName: DS.attr(),
    lastName: DS.attr(),
    **debits: DS.hasMany('debit'),**
    **credits: DS.hasMany('credit')**
}
```

How can I accomplish this in ember-data?

JSbin - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gewowucamo/8/edit?html,js,output

Comment: polymorphic relationships?

Comment: polymorphics are mixed data type array but still get data from the server. not built using other data type content.

Comment: Question: what you've described is (basically) what should be working for you.. Apart from a few small things (e.g. `DS.belongsTo()` should be `DS.belongsTo('person')`).. Is it just these small things you need help with to get you going or are you running into a particular bug/error when you're trying to implement it?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have fixed it now. Question is that first section of the code is the data I'm getting through api. Now after fetching all the data for person, credit, debit. How do I build hasMany under person for debits and credits dynamically.

Comment: So everything in your question should be working fine for you.. If you remove the ** before and ** after the `DS.hasMany` (obviously - since it's not correct syntax) - I don't see why that wouldn't work... Once you load all the person objects, they will have nothing in their debits/credits fields.. Then once you load all the debit/credit objects, it will update the appropriate person objects, adding each credit/debit to the persons debits/credits hasMany field it belongs to.. It should all work automatically for you

Comment: Do you need to use Ember Data?  Are you performing CRUD on the debits/credits, or are they purely informational?

Comment: I'm using Ember Data. Just informational. This is the same example in jsbin - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gewowucamo/8/edit?html,js,output It is not working as indicated by @jmurphyau

Comment: hashg I created a working JSBin before telling you it would work.. Basically I think it's not working for you because you're using Fixtures.. I'll provide the JSBin link in a few hours (don't have access to it ATM)

Answer (score 1):

Everything you're doing will work. When you load the data using `store.push()` it builds the related relationships for you (if they exist).

[This JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fitero/2/edit?js,output) gives you an example of what you're doing that works.

I believe the problem you have is likely related to using Fixtures - and at a guess I would assume it doesn't follow the same behaviour/logic when loading data.

Fixtures are being removed from Ember (see [this PR](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/3091))

Answer (score 0):

You have already answered your own questions, as the code you have given should already work.

Comment: This is the same example in jsbin - emberjs.jsbin.com/gewowucamo/8/edit?html,js,output It is not working